# How do I create virtual I/O with jack?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

I've recently been trying to configure some audio/music performance setting.

I've been messing around with internal I/O with Jack, hoping to find a way to create some virtual inputs and outputs channels to route between separate tracks in DAWs. Currently I have 10 ins and 10 outs, which is a default setting on my hardware audio interface (IconnectAudio4+), but I was hoping to add some extra I/O on top of this. Some of the search results on this matter seem to suggest that this is possible, but I can't find a way to do this. Can someone help me? I am on Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS. (64bit)

Thank you!

Comment: What research have you seen? What are you trying to accomplish with virtual I/O audio?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make tracks of two different DAWs send and receive audio to and from each other through virtual channels. My audio interface already has 4 hardware ins and outs, and 6 virtual i/o channels, so I can already make it work on these 6 input and output channels. I'd just like to have more of these channels, if possible.

Comment: is there a reason why you can not connect output from one DAW to input of the other? audio connections in JACK can be connected internally without needing hardware or virtual i/o. Considering the number of connections you are intending to manage, suggest you use Patchage to get a good view of available connections. Edit your OP to post screenshot of What is already available in Patchage and explain more what you are trying to achieve